# using Python, how can I get and print to html Twilio logs?

Tags: python, twilio

I want to get Twilio SMS logs and print them out as HTML. The code is:

```
from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient

@application.route("/logs", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def logs():

    client = TwilioRestClient(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN)
    data = client.sms.messages.list()
    return data
```

this returns an error as follows:

```
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1478, in full_dispatch_request
response = self.make_response(rv)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1577, in make_response
rv = self.response_class.force_type(rv, request.environ)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/wrappers.py", line 841, in force_type
response = BaseResponse(*_run_wsgi_app(response, environ))
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/wrappers.py", line 57, in _run_wsgi_app
return _run_wsgi_app(*args)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/test.py", line 867, in run_wsgi_app
app_rv = app(environ, start_response)
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Does "list object is not callable" mean the object is empty or somehting else? What is the correct way to do this and get an object returned that I can parse as json?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: `app` is a list, that's what that means. Why? Short a [mcve] that's not clear.

Comment: thank you and sorry I don't understand what you mean, there seems to be mutual miscomprehension. The error indicates something has gone wrong and I don't know what has gone wrong. I want to be able to read the http response and print some if it out as html. The http response is json data and an example is here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sms#list

Comment: Try `data = client.sms.messages.list`, i.e.: without the parentheses.

Comment: thank you, sorry does not work. The error is "StopIteration".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output from [`data = client.sms.messages.list()`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sms#list-get-filters) should look like this:

```
"page": 0,
    "page_size": 50,
    "uri": "/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/SMS/Messages.json"
    "first_page_uri": "/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/SMS/Messages.json?Page=0&PageSize=50",
    "next_page_uri": "/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/SMS/Messages.json?Page=1&PageSize=50",
    "previous_page_uri": null,
    "sms_messages": [
        {
            "account_sid": "ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
            "api_version": "2008-08-01",
            "body": "A message from StackOverflow.",
            "date_created": "Mon, 16 Aug 2010 03:45:01 +0000",
            "date_sent": "Mon, 16 Aug 2010 03:45:03 +0000",
            "date_updated": "Mon, 16 Aug 2010 03:45:03 +0000",
            "direction": "outbound-api",
            "from": "+14158141829",
            "price": "-0.02000",
            "sid": "SM800f449d0399ed014aae2bcc0cc2f2ec",
            "status": "sent",
            "to": "+14159978453",
            "uri": "/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/SMS/Messages/SM800f449d0399ed014aae2bcc0cc2f2ec.json"
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

Check out the [FAQ](https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/twilio-basics/how-do-i-export-my-smscall-logs) about retrieving logs and let me know if this helps at all.

Comment: thank you, this has now been fixed by using the API Explorer. The snippet of code I was looking for was for m in messages print m.sid thank you